# Modifying a config section saves that section to a different config file

Tags: c#, encryption, configuration, app-config

I have `myapp.somenamespace.exe.config` file with a connectionStrings section, which I need to encrypt. Also there are some other config settings that I want intact. So I wrote this small tool that would do just that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EncryptSection("myapp.somenamespace.exe.config", "connectionStrings");
    }
    static void EncryptSection(string fileName, string sectionName)
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(fileName);

        var section = config.GetSection(sectionName);

        if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected) return;

        secction.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");

        config.Save();
    }
}
```

What happens, it creates a new config file named `myapp.somenamespace.exe.config.config` - adding a duplicate `.config` extension, which only contains the encrypted section. It does **not** modify the original config file.

Any ideas why such an odd behavior and how I could fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
EncryptSection("myapp.somenamespace.exe.config", "connectionStrings");
```

to this:

```
EncryptSection("myapp.somenamespace.exe", "connectionStrings");
```

[the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) states that the first parameter is in fact `he path of the executable (exe) file` and thus it's tacking on an additional `.config` during `Save`.

Comment: @Andrey, I'm glad I could be of assistance!